# chmod 755 permissions for created files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, chmod

I'm running Ubuntu Server 18.04.01 and am somewhat a noob when it comes to Linux permissions settings.

I have application A which is creating files and dumping them in a directory, and application B which is then taking those files, processing them and moving them somewhere else.

The problem I have is that application B is reporting that it cannot access the files created by application A. I can get around this by manually SSH'ing onto the server and running:

```
sudo chmod 775 -R ./Directory
```

However this is tedious and more importantly, requires human input. The whole purpose of my server is to automate some home security tasks so manual intervention is not feasible.

Please could someone let me know how I can make sure that all files created by application A, have rwx permissions for application B?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. I'm so used to using stack overflow for development related stuff that it didn't occur to me that my question was more oriented towards the linux stack exchange. Fair point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the type of application A (is it a script or is it a binary?) you could just add to have it change the permissions once it created it.

If the application is a binary, you can "enclose" it into a script, which changes the [umask](https://linux.die.net/man/2/umask) before and during its runtime or change the permissions once the application stops running (e.g. as final task of the script).

Another approach is to run application A as the same user as application B is running, if this is feasible.

Comment: Thanks, the application is binary but I have the source so I can see about getting it to change permissions - I was rather hoping there would be some neat way of doing it without having to re-build, oh well :)

Thanks for the answer btw, not sure why someone down voted you, I thought it was helpful.

Comment: By default applications will use the umask setting to set permissions.  If you enclose the application in a small 2- or 3-line script with the umask set to 0002, recompiling should not be necessary as the application will then store using the permissions 775.  Once the script is over or any other scripts run in parallel will continue to use the system's umask.  So, it will not interfere.